# Conditional compilation of fastScrollThumbDrawable?

Tags: android, api, fastscroll

I have an app with min API 10, and I set `fastScrollEnabled` to true. Now, the `fastScrollThumbDrawable` is really horrible, and I want to change it. I can add in the `style.xml` the line

```
<item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb</item>
```

The problem is that `android:fastScrollThumbDrawable` only works for API 11+, and API10 does not let me to compile with that line (eclipse). So I want to set `android:fastScrollThumbDrawable` programatically when API >= 11, otherwise stay with the horrible one.

The problem is that I couldn't find a way of setting `android:fastScrollThumbDrawable` programatically... Is this possible? Is there any way to circumvent this?

Thanks!
L.

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: 18. But Benito's answer works great. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *res* folder create a folder called *values-v11*.

Inside this folder create a file called *style.xml*

This file will be specific to API level 11 and above.

Comment: still its showing error in xml, when i compile with 2.3.3 @Benito Bertoli